# How to get the correct result when I use re.compile(pattern), if the pattern contains some special characters, like, (),?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a string in a file using python `re` lib. But I failed on replacing some texts with some special characters, like, `()`, `?`, etc. Can anyone help me look at this issue?

I attached my code in here.:

```python
filterText = '\"' + sheet.row_values(row)[1] + '\"';
print "filterText = %s"%filterText;
pattern = re.compile(filterText, re.S);
replacedText = '\"' + sheet.row_values(row)[2] + '\"';
print "replacedText = %s"%replacedText;

if filterText == "English (UK)":
    print "replacedText = %s"%replacedText;

fileContent = re.sub(pattern, replacedText, fileContent);
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be Python? Then why all the semicolons?

Comment: And you'll need to show examples of the contents. Are you sure you need regexes here?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Acturally, I am trying to convert a file with English words to another language. I got an excel from customer which contains English text and Vietnamese together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [re.**escape**(*string*)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape)
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

Use `re.escape` to convert any string as a literal pattern.

```
filterText = '\"' + re.escape(sheet.row_values(row)[1]) + '\"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works totally. :)  Thank you very much.